# Unresolved Inclusion: Eclipse Not Showing "Includes" tab under "Paths and Symbols":

Tags: c++, eclipse

I am trying to resolve some inclusions in Eclipse. Normally I click on project properties, then 'C/C++ General', then 'Paths and Symbols', then start adding include directories, as is shown here:
[image: Normal way to include paths.]

But today, for some strange reason, Eclipse (Juno) is not showing the includes tab![image: My version of eclipse.]

How can I get the 'Includes' tab back so I can resolve the symbols in my project?

Comment: The item below "Paths and Symbols" on the left looks like it might say something like "Preprocessor Include Paths". Did you look in there?

Comment: I looked in there. It said "Cannot determine toolchain languages".

Answer (score 1):

The tab is hidden by default, you can enable it again by entering:

Windows > Preferences > C/C++ > Property Pages Settings > Display "Include Files" ...

You might have to restart Eclipse in order for it to show.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may come from the fact that the  CDT plugin does not recognize the language toolchain.

You can fix this in the your project properties `C/C++ General > Language Mapping`. Just add a mapping for all configurations, mappin each content type to the Gnu C++ Language.

After that, restart Eclipse for the changes to take effect